# MS Access: Left outer self join with inequality operator

Tags: ms-access

I have a single table in Access 2010:

```
TMP [CUST,ITEM,START_PD]
```

I want to get the END_PD for each CUST / ITEM.

END_PD being defined as the period before the next higher START_PD for the same CUST / ITEM.

So I perform a left join of the table to itself, using an inequality operator on START_PD as below.

```
SELECT s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD, Min(e.START_PD-1) AS END_PD
FROM TMP AS s 
LEFT JOIN TMP AS e ON s.CUST=e.CUST AND s.ITEM=e.ITEM AND e.START_PD>s.START_PD
GROUP BY s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD
ORDER BY s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD
```

The base table has 46,556 rows.  I would expect the query result to have the same, but the query only returns 14,967 rows.

Even when I try to return all records in the left join, I get far less than the base table. See below:

```
SELECT s.*,e.*
FROM TMP AS s 
LEFT JOIN TMP AS e ON s.ITEM = e.ITEM AND s.CUST = e.CUST AND e.START_PD>s.START_PD
```

The above query only returns 19,014 records... less than the base table.

This is holding up a major project, and I'd appreciate any help.  So far, it's looking like an Access bug.  Any workarounds?

EDIT:
I have tried testing a small sample of the data by including `WHERE s.CUST='WALMART' AND s.ITEM='0001H'`.  This fails by excluding the last START_PD, for which there is none greater.

```
CUST    ITEM    START_PD    END_PD
WALMART 0001HAC 20694   20696
WALMART 0001HAC 20697   20704
WALMART 0001HAC 20705   20706
```

Strangely, if I select that same sample of the data (WALMART/0001H) into a separate table and run the EXACT SAME query on that smaller table (changing only the table name), it works fine as below.  That is why I tend to think this is a bug.

```
CUST    ITEM    START_PD    END_PD
WALMART 0001HAC 20694   20696
WALMART 0001HAC 20697   20704
WALMART 0001HAC 20705   20706
WALMART 0001HAC 20707
```

Comment: Please provide some data plus actual results and expected results. It's definitely not an Access bug, it's your query that doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Your first query works fine as long as all combinations of CUST, ITEM and START_PD are unique. Also take into account that you can't derive an END_PD for the most recent CUST/ITEM/START_PD combinations.

Comment: @Rene Thanks. I have tried to reproduce the error on a small sample of the data for demo purposes, but can't.  I'll include an edit about this.

Comment: Interesting that you say CUST, ITEM and START_PD need to be unique -- I don't see why that would be.

Comment: I know you can't derive an END_PD for the most recent CUST/ITEM/START_PD.  I want the END_PD to show null in that case.  This will indicate an indefinite end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I'd like to:

1. Demonstrate that this is a bug
2. Provide a workaround

### Proof that this is a bug.

```
    Sub Test()
        Dim db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
        Set db = CurrentDb

        On Error Resume Next
        db.QueryDefs.Delete "TMP_EXTENDED"
        db.QueryDefs.Delete "RAW_LEFT_JOIN"
        db.TableDefs.Delete "TMP"
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Table definition.
        strSql = _
        "CREATE TABLE TMP ( " & vbCrLf & _
        "  CUST VARCHAR(10), " & vbCrLf & _
        "  ITEM VARCHAR(10), " & vbCrLf & _
        "  START_PD LONG, " & vbCrLf & _
        "  PRIMARY KEY (CUST,ITEM,START_PD) " & vbCrLf & _
        ");"
        db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError

        'Populate with data.
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("TMP")
        For custNo = 1 To 25      'change to affect final row count
            For itemNo = 1 To 100 'change to affect final row count
                For pdNo = 1 To 3 'change to affect final row count
                    strCust = "CUST" & custNo
                    strItem = "ITEM" & itemNo
                    rst.AddNew
                    rst("CUST") = strCust
                    rst("ITEM") = strItem
                    rst("START_PD") = pdNo
                    rst.Update
                    If rst.RecordCount Mod 1000 = 0 Then Debug.Print rst.RecordCount 'just to monitor.
                Next
            Next
        Next
        Debug.Print "TMP Table Row Count is: " & DCount("*", "TMP")

        'Test query to find end period for each CUST/ITEM/START_PD.
        Dim qdf As New QueryDef
        qdf.Name = "TMP_EXTENDED"
        qdf.SQL = "SELECT s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD, Min(e.START_PD-1) AS END_PD " & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM TMP AS s  " & vbCrLf & _
        "LEFT JOIN TMP AS e ON (s.CUST=e.CUST AND s.ITEM=e.ITEM AND e.START_PD>s.START_PD) " & vbCrLf & _
        "GROUP BY s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD " & vbCrLf & _
        "ORDER BY s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD"
        db.QueryDefs.Append qdf
        Debug.Print "TMP_EXTENDED Row Count is: " & DCount("*", "TMP_EXTENDED")

        'Test query to just perform the left join.
        Set qdf = New QueryDef
        qdf.Name = "RAW_LEFT_JOIN"
        qdf.SQL = "SELECT s.*,e.* " & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM TMP AS s  " & vbCrLf & _
        "LEFT JOIN TMP AS e ON s.ITEM = e.ITEM AND s.CUST = e.CUST AND e.START_PD>s.START_PD"
        db.QueryDefs.Append qdf
        Debug.Print "RAW_LEFT_JOIN Row Count is: " & DCount("*", "RAW_LEFT_JOIN")

        RefreshDatabaseWindow

    End Sub
```

When run as written, the above code returns:

```
TMP Table Row Count is: 7500
TMP_EXTENDED Row Count is: 5000
RAW_LEFT_JOIN Row Count is: 7500
```

Obviously this is wrong because a left join should always return all the records in the left table.  In this case, TMP_EXTENDED should have returned 7500, and RAW_LEFT_JOIN should have returned *more than* 7500.

The loop bounds for `custNo`, `itemNo`, and `pdNo` can be changed to adjust the record count in table TMP.  If you do this, you will see that ***the query works until the record count reaches about 7000, then it fails***.

The same problem does not appear to exist when the join is only performed on one 'entity' column. For example, I modified the above code to use a table with only a `CUST` column and `START_PD` column, and got both queries to work properly on a table record count of 600,000.

### Workaround

Since posting this, I have found another quite similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573561/outer-join-result-is-missing-rows-no-where-clause-workaround-found?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which a decent [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573665/5656296) is presented. I have modified it as below.  I do not know HOW reliable it is going to be, but I'm going with it for now.

```
    SELECT s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD, Min(e.START_PD) AS END_PD
    FROM TMP AS s INNER JOIN TMP AS e ON s.ITEM = e.ITEM AND s.CUST = e.CUST
    WHERE e.START_PD>s.START_PD
    GROUP BY s.CUST, s.ITEM, s.START_PD

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CUST, ITEM, Max(START_PD), Null 
    FROM TMP
    GROUP BY CUST, ITEM, Null
    ORDER BY CUST,ITEM,START_PD,END_PD
```

Answer (score 0):

Any "atypical" (not only table1.field = table2.field, but anything with constants, calculations, or comparison operators other than equality) join in Access should have it's `ON` clause surrounded by braces:

```
SELECT s.*,e.*
FROM TMP AS s 
LEFT JOIN TMP AS e ON (s.ITEM = e.ITEM AND s.CUST = e.CUST AND e.START_PD>s.START_PD)
```

However, usually, these kinds of joins return a *Join expression not supported* error instead of giving incorrect results. I don't know why this one doesn't.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks... At any rate, I just tried using braces in the `ON` clause and it did not have an impact on my (bad) query results.

Comment: That's odd. Are there null values in any of the columns you're joining on?

Comment: No sir, no null values.  And all CUST/ITEM/START_PD combinations are unique.

Comment: That's strange. I can't reproduce the issue, then